# Observe LiveData instance in fragment and activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I have a simple scenario where I do something in fragment and when I receive the LiveData I want to do something in Activity.

ViewModel:

```kotlin
class MyViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    
   ...
    
    fun getUser(id: String): LiveData<User> {
        return repository.getUser(id)
    }
}
```

Fragment:

```kotlin
class MyFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var myViewModel: MyViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        activity?.run {
            myViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
        } ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            showProgressBar()
            myViewModel.getUser(editText.text.toString()).observe(this, Observer { it ->
                //TODO
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Activity:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var myViewModel: MyViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        myViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
        //Here I would like to observe the user instance returned from the getUser() method
    }
}
```

So the issue I'm having is that I would like to have an instance of `LiveData<User>` in `MyViewModel` so that I could observe it in Activity and Fragment. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can share the ViewModel between the activity and fragment....pass parent activity instance to `ViewModelProviders.of()` in your fragment (or even better use `sharedViewModel` if using Koin!)

Comment: I think I'm doing that already, the `this` instance that I'm passing to `ViewModelProviders.of()` is the activity itself

Comment: Save user data from FragmentViewModel to database .Define another viewModel for your activity and subscribe your Activity to observe changes in this database . 
I think this will be much more cleaner  to implement and understand @NelsonAlmendra

Answer (score 12):

In Fragemnts (as best practice) Should Use

```
viewModel.userLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
    //your code here
})
```

In Activity Use

```
viewModel.userLiveData.observe(this, Observer {
        //your code here
    })
```

Answer (score 4):

in class MyViewModel create

```
    val userLiveData =MutableLiveData<User>()
```

and getter

```
    fun getUserLiveData(id: String): MutableLiveData<User> {
            return userLiveData
    }

    fun getUser(id: String){
    val disposableUser = repository.getUser(id)
    .subscribe({
        userLivedata.postValue(it)
    })
```

}

And in activity or Fragment called

```
   myViewModel.getUserLiveData.observe(this, Observer { it ->
      //TODO
    })
   myViewModel.getUser(...)
```

And Now in ViewModel you have object User (userLiveData.getValue())

Answer (score 1):

Write method in Activity `doSomethingWithUser(user: User)`

And in your livedata

```
myViewModel.getUser(editText.text.toString()).observe(this, Observer { it ->
            (requireActivity() as MainActivity).doSomethingWithUser(it)
        })
```